# Apache unicode handling

Tags: php, apache, encoding

I'm trying to duplicate existing apache behavior in a new server, but first need to understand how the current (Red Hat 4.4.7-23) one is working.

The following php:

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect("user", "password", "database");
$statement = oci_parse($conn, "select substr(description,10,10) desc_raw, asciistr(substr(description,10,10)) desc_ascii from aradmin.CHG_INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE where asciistr(description) != description and rownum < 2");
$success = oci_execute($statement, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
if ($success) {
    oci_fetch_all($statement, $dataRows, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
    echo "desc_raw: " . $dataRowsi[0]['DESC_RAW'] . '<br>';
    echo "desc_ascii: " . $dataRows[0]['DESC_ASCII'] . '<br>';
    echo "json_encode(desc_raw): " . json_encode($dataRows[0]['DESC_RAW']) . '<br>';
}
oci_free_statement($statement);
oci_close($conn);
```

Generates this output when run form the command line:

```
desc_raw: 08:00 ▒ 17<br>desc_ascii: 08:00 \00BF 17<br>json_encode(desc_raw): <br>
```

Note that the json_encode fails because of the rogue unicode character.

When requested via apache I instead get:

```
desc_raw: 08:00 ? 17<br>desc_ascii: 08:00 \00BF 17<br>json_encode(desc_raw): "08:00 ? 17"<br>
```

I have a lot of code that assumes this behavior, which is fine except my new environment gives the cli response.

Here's my current httpd.conf:

```
$ egrep -v '^($| *#)' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
ServerTokens OS
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid
Timeout 60
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 300
KeepAliveTimeout 5
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers            12
MinSpareServers         12
MaxSpareServers         12
ServerLimit             150
MaxClients              150
MaxRequestsPerChild     0
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
Listen *:80
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
Include conf.d/*.conf
ExtendedStatus On
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin <redacted>
ServerName <redacted>:80
UseCanonicalName Off
DocumentRoot "/<redacted>"
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT PRODUCTION
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir disabled
</IfModule>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm index.html.var
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
DefaultType text/plain
<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog /<redacted>/error_log
LogLevel warn
LogFormat "%h %D %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %D" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
CustomLog /<redacted>/access_log combined
ServerSignature On
Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"
<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8
AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip
AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*
AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core
AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^
DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif
ReadmeName README.html
HeaderName HEADER.html
IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t
AddLanguage ca .ca
AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
AddLanguage da .dk
AddLanguage de .de
AddLanguage el .el
AddLanguage en .en
AddLanguage eo .eo
AddLanguage es .es
AddLanguage et .et
AddLanguage fr .fr
AddLanguage he .he
AddLanguage hr .hr
AddLanguage it .it
AddLanguage ja .ja
AddLanguage ko .ko
AddLanguage ltz .ltz
AddLanguage nl .nl
AddLanguage nn .nn
AddLanguage no .no
AddLanguage pl .po
AddLanguage pt .pt
AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br
AddLanguage ru .ru
AddLanguage sv .sv
AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw
LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TW
ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
AddHandler type-map var
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Allow from all
</Location>
<Location /server-info>
    SetHandler server-info
    Allow from all
</Location>

$ egrep -v '^($| *#)' /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:AddHandler php5-script .php
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:AddType text/html .php
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:DirectoryIndex index.php
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:php_value session.save_handler "files"
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:php_value soap.wsdl_cache_dir  "/var/lib/php/wsdlcache"
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:Listen 443
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLMutex default
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLCryptoDevice builtin
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:<VirtualHost _default_:443>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:LogLevel warn
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLEngine on
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLCipherSuite DEFAULT:!EXP:!SSLv2:!DES:!IDEA:!SEED:+3DES
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLCertificateFile <redacted>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLCertificateKeyFile <redacted>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:</Files>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:</Directory>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:</VirtualHost>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf:LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf:LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf:<Location /svn>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf:  DAV svn
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf:  SVNPath /opt/repo/
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf:  AuthType Basic
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf:  AuthName "SVN Repo"
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf:  AuthUserFile /opt/WANdisco/apache22/conf/svn.passwd
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf:  Require valid-user
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf:</Location>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf:<LocationMatch "^/+$">
/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf:    Options -Indexes
/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf:    ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf:</LocationMatch>
```

Can someone please tell me which apache directive is responsible for this behaviour?

Edit:

Prompted by comments here and elsewhere I have run the page with alternative `oci_connect("user", "password", "database");` calls to specify character set with results as follows:

Original:
`oci_connect("user", "password", "database");` json_encode includes `?`

The correct character set for the database:
`oci_connect("user", "password", "database", "WE8ISO8859P15");` json_encode fails (i.e. the worst possible outcome)

An incorrect character set for the database:
`oci_connect("user", "password", "database", "UTF8");` json_encode includes `\u00bf` (this I can probably live with but I don't know what other impacts it might have)

Comment: You should probably _specify_ the connection character set in your `oci_connect` call in the first place, instead of implicitly relying on some configuration setting hidden somewhere.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php: _“If not specified, the Oracle Client libraries determine a character set from the NLS_LANG environment variable. […] Passing this parameter can reduce the time taken to connect.”_

Comment: That's great but my existing code doesn't specify a connect character (and even when I do for the purposes of this test it doesn't change the behavior, I've tried).

Comment: Then check what NLS_LANG contains in each case.

Comment: NLS_LANG is undefined in both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

php must be compiled with mbstring support

for php7.4 that's the `--enable-mbstring` option in configure.